# SQL where to query in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I type:

```
User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07").where("updated_at > created_at + 1.day").count
```

Error Returned:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2015-08-06' AND '2015-08-07' AND (updated_at > created_at + 1.day)ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'day)' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2015-08-06' AND '2015-08-07' AND (updated_at > created_at + 1.day)

from /home/guinness/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in query'
```

What's wrong with this? As you know I want to know how many users retained after 1 day of their sign up.

Comment: `created_at + 1.day` is not recognized by SQL.

Comment: Then how can I get what I want?

Comment: I think this is not the current synrtax for 1 day interval in mysql. Read the docs first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1.day` is ruby syntax, not sql.  try this:

```
 User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07").where("updated_at > DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)").count
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Comment: Or he could do `User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07").where("updated_at > ?", created_at + 1.day).count`

Comment: I think that will error with `unknown variable or method "created_at"`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07").where("updated_at > ?", created_at + 1.day).count
```

Comment: Not going to work, I think, because "created_at" is an instance method. You can't use it in this context.

Comment: yup .. got my mistake. It should be  User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07").where("updated_at > DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)").count